# Decompose $\Lambda^3(V \otimes W)$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra

Let $V, W$ be two vector spaces. We have $\Lambda^2(V \otimes W) \cong (\Lambda^2 V \otimes S^2 W) \oplus (S^2 V \otimes \Lambda^2 W)$. I am trying to find similar results for $\Lambda^3(V \otimes W)$. I think that $\Lambda^3 V \otimes S^3 W$ and $S^3 V \otimes \Lambda^3 W$ are subspaces of $\Lambda^3(V \otimes W)$. It seems that $\Lambda^3(V \otimes W)$ has other subspaces since if the dimensions of $V$ and $W$ are $n, m$ respectively, then the dimension of $\Lambda^3(V \otimes W)$ is $\frac{m\, n\, \left(m\, n - 1\right)\, \left(m\, n - 2\right)}{6}$ and the sum of dimensions of  $\Lambda^3 V \otimes S^3 W$ and $S^3 V \otimes \Lambda^3 W$ is $\frac{m\, n\, \left(m^2\, n^2 + 2\, m^2 - 9\, m\, n + 2\, n^2 + 4\right)}{18}$. The difference of these two numbers is $\frac{m\, n\, \left(n - 1\right)\, \left(n + 1\right)\, \left(m - 1\right)\, \left(m + 1\right)}{9}$. Therefore we have
$$
\Lambda^3(V \otimes W) \cong  (\Lambda^3 V \otimes S^3 W) \oplus (S^3 V \otimes \Lambda^3 W) \oplus W_1.
$$
How to compute $W_1$ explicitly? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You mixed $V$ and $W$ in such a way that your post is illegible. Please correct, and add parentheses.

Comment: @abx, thank you very much. I have added the parentheses.

Comment: Instead of computing the dimension, you can try computing the character (that is, the trace of the action of a pair consisting of a diagonal matrix acting on $V$ and on $W$), then decompose the corresponding characters.

Comment: It seems that your question is very related to the notion of "symmetry classes of tensors", you can see "Multilinear algebra" by R. Merris, where there are  many  similar decomposition for symmetry classes.

Comment: Your first formula cannot be right, since $W$ does not appear on the right hand side.

Comment: @Daniel Litt, corrected.

Comment: A stronger hint:  For any vector space $V$ of dimension $n$, the kernel of the natural map $V\otimes S^2(V)\to S^3(V)$ is an irreducible $\mathrm{GL}(V)$-module of dimension $n(n-1)(n+1)/3$, and your $W_1$ must be a sum of tensor products of $\mathrm{GL}(V)$-modules with  $\mathrm{GL}(W)$-modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**
The group $GL(V)\times GL(W)$ acts naturally on $\wedge^n(V\otimes W)$ for any  $n\in \mathbb{N}$ (in your case $n=3$). One can describe decomposition of this space into irreducible components. For example for $n=2$ the decomposition you described coincides with that one.

Any irreducible representation of $GL(V)\times GL(W)$ has the form $\pi\otimes \rho$ where $\pi$ and $\rho$ are irreducible representation of $GL(V)$ and $GL(W)$ respectively.
In our case relevant irreducible representations $\pi$ and $\rho$ of $GL(V)$ and $GL(W)$ are parameterized by Young diagrams with $n$ cells. Moreover for every irreducible component $\pi\otimes \rho$  the corresponding to $\pi$ and $\rho$ Young diagrams are transposed to each other (and have $n$ cells). Any such pair of diagrams appears in the decomposition at most once, and in fact exactly once provided the dimensions of $V$ and $W$ are large enough. Thus for $n=3$ there are three such diagrams, hence 3 irreducible components. The first two summands you wrote in this case are the two irreducible $GL(V)\times GL(W)$-components.
The last summand is the tensor product of two Young diagrams both equal to $(2,1)$, i.e. in the first row there are two cells, and in the second one only one cell. Actually is was described in the comment by Robert Bryant as the kernel of the symmetrization map $V\otimes S^2(V)\to S^3(V)$. Similarly for $W$.

In representation theoretical literature there is a lot of information about the properties of representations with given Young diagram, e.g. how to compute the dimension. See e.g. the paper "Remarks on classical invariant theory" by R. Howe, p. 560. The space can be described explicitly using e.g. Young symmetrizers.

Comment: thank you very much. Can we write $W_1$ in terms of $V$ and $W$?

Comment: $W_1$ us isomorphic to $Ker(V\otimes S^2(V)\to S^3(V))\otimes Ker(W\otimes S^2(W)\to S^3(W))$.